# How should I remove class from attribure when adding it to another?

Tags: python

I want to create atributes in one class taking it from another. Here's my code:

```
def copy_class_attrs(cls):
    def __provide_attr(decorated_class):
        for f in cls.__dict__:
            if not f.startswith("__") or not f.endswith("__"):
                setattr(decorated_class, f, getattr(cls, f))
        return decorated_class
    return __provide_attr

class A:
    a = 0
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
    def increment(self):
        self.a += 1

@copy_class_attrs(A)
class B:
    b = 0
    def __init__(self):
        self.b = 1
```

but in `B.__dict__` I see `'increment': <function __main__.A.increment(self)>`. How should I remove A. from `increment` method in B?

Comment: The function you copied over *is* `A.increment`. If you want a function that isn't `A.increment`, you'll have to make a new function.

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to achieve? ``__main__.A.increment`` is the path to the function definition. Why do you want to remove ``A`` from it? It's where the function is. The function is a method of A/B by being part of the class'  dict; the path has nothing to do with it.

Comment: I want B class has attribute with same name and meaning. In that case B should have `increment` method, based in itself, with no referring to A class. I hope I explained it clearly now.

Comment: B class *has* a method ``increment``. That method being initially defined on ``A`` does in no way impact its functionality or meaning. Can you clarify what specific *behaviour* you desire, and in how far the current solution differs from it?

Comment: This code must create in `B` class all non-magic attributes of `A` class without referring to `A` class. So in `B` class attribute `a` must appear and method `increment` must appear which increases attribute `a`. In the implementation with the current code `increment` method in `B` has referring to `A` which expressed in `.A. ` in `increment` method in `B.__dict__`

Comment: Can you please clarify why the function being defined inside A is an observable problem? For practical purposes, this has no effect on the functionality of B. Either there is no such problem, in which case your code is fine, or there is and it impacts what solutions are appropriate. Is it fine for the method inside A to refer to B?

Comment: It's just my task. I don't think such referring has any practical problems, it are just formal requisities. I think if I am able to rename method in `B` in order to remove any mentions of A it will solve the problem.

Comment: If you have some formal requirements, can you please state them verbatim?

Comment: Describe the class decorator that accepts another class as an input and supplies the class to be decorated with all the attributes of the input class, whose names are NOT framed on both sides by `__`. At the same time, private field attributes (starting in the declaration with `__`) must have a valid name in the decorated class.

In case of name conflicts, the imported attribute should be given a name with the suffix `_new`.